# How can I create a 64bit calculator in assembly using only 32bit registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

I want to create a 64bit calculator (operations: +, -, *, / ) using only 32bit registers. I have to read a string from the console, convert it into a mathematical expression ( ex: 123+4321 so I must convert it into two numbers 123 and 4321 and I have to add them). Please give me an idea, how to represent in the memory a 64bit number, and how to implement the addition using only 32bit registers!

Comment: I created an array with two elements, like num DD 2 DUP (0) and I tried to save the first 32 bits in num(0) and the last 32 bits in num(1). I have successfully saved the last 32 bits in num(1) but I don't know what to do if I have a bigger number, how to use the carry?

Comment: Use `add` to add the low dwords, then `adc` to add the top dwords and the carry. Similarly with `sub` and `sbb`. For multiplication and division the architecture already provides 64 bit operations. Consult an instruction set reference.

Comment: The fundamental answer is, "read up on the Intel instruction set" and read up on "multiprecision arithmetic".

Answer (score 0):

If this is X86, or other little endian processor, then you should store the low order 32 bits in the first word, and the high order 32 bits in the second word (this is how DD's are stored). Addition and subtraction just need to make use of the carry / borrow bit.

Multiplication is done similar to long hand. You can reduce the number of multiplies to 3 using [Karatsuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) , but I'm not sure if it would save much time since multiply is fairly fast.

Division is done similar to long hand. If you have a divide that uses two 32 bit registers for the dividend, like X86 which uses EDX, EAX, that helps (although the size of the quotient is limited to 32 bits). The general method is to iterate a few time to produce an estimated quotient that converges on the actual quotient. There are several methods for doing this. You can do a web search for 64 bit divide to find examples of how to do this.